# Type a pipe method that repeatedly destructures properties and adds new ones

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a dictionary that can be populated by piping functions that have the following form: take in an object (dictionary), destructure its properties to use as arguments, and return an object with new properties (that then can then be added to the dictionary).

Is there any way to type the pipe function such that only the properties that have been previously added can be destructured? I.e.:

```
type AugmentFun = (source: Record<string, any>) => Record<string, any>;

class Pipeable {
  constructor(private dict: Record<string, any>) {}

  static of = (dict: Record<string, any>) => new Pipeable(dict);
  static augment = (source: Pipeable, fun: AugmentFun) => {
    return Pipeable.of(Object.assign({}, source.dict, fun(source.dict)));
  };

  pipe = (...funs: AugmentFun[]) => funs.reduce(Pipeable.augment, this);
}

const p = new Pipeable({});

// This works & should not throw type errors
const res1 = p.pipe(
  () => ({ a: 1, b: 2 }),       // { a: 1, b: 2 }
  ({ a, b }) => ({ c: a + b }), // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  ({ c }) => ({ d: c ** 2 })    // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 9}
);

// This should throw type errors but doesn't
const res2 = p.pipe(
  () => ({ a: 1, b: 2 }),       // { a: 1, b: 2 }
  ({ c }) => ({ d: c + 10 })    // Should be: "c" does not exist
);
```

(the `augment()` method is pure, but it could also just as well mutate the original instance, that's not too important)

Comment: You probably need to use generics instead of using `Record<string, any>`. Check out Redux's `compose` function for an example of how to type a chain of functions like this. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.ts

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem; but sadly there is no first-class support to type pipes of an unknown amount of dependent functions in TypeScript. The only "*non-hacky*" solution is to use overloads.

```
class Pipeable {
  constructor(private dict: Record<string, any>) {}

  static of = (dict: Record<string, any>) => new Pipeable(dict);
  static augment = (source: Pipeable, fun: AugmentFun) => {
    return Pipeable.of(Object.assign({}, source.dict, fun(source.dict)));
  };

  pipe<A>(fn1: () => A): A
  pipe<A, B>(fn1: () => A, fn2: (arg: A) => B): B
  pipe<A, B, C>(fn1: () => A, fn2: (arg: A) => B, fn3: (arg: A & B) => C): C
  pipe<A, B, C, D>(
    fn1: () => A, 
    fn2: (arg: A) => B, 
    fn3: (arg: A & B) => C, 
    fn4: (arg: A & B & C) => D
  ): D
  pipe(...funs: AugmentFun[]){ 
    funs.reduce(Pipeable.augment, this) 
  }
}
```

This requires us to have the same amount of overloads as we the number of operators we want to support. Because of the lack of alternatives, this pattern is used for the typing of `.pipe` in RxJS and pipes in other libraries.

```
const p = new Pipeable({});

const res1 = p.pipe(
  () => ({ a: 1, b: 2 }),             // { a: 1, b: 2 }
  ({ a, b }) => ({ c: a + b }),       // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  ({ a, b, c }) => ({ d: c ** 2 })    // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 9}
);

const res2 = p.pipe(
  () => ({ a: 1, b: 2 }),     
  ({ c }) => ({ d: c + 10 })  
//   ~ Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ a: number; b: number; }'
);
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-k4AB+ZjkCQkDkKAUAAOSUGpwkkJOUCoCQ44QAAHo247UVAoCQOp7GoHASBWBA5DqHhel2Q5Tk7mpOidEAA)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's quite unfortunate. Hopefully future version might support something like this.